# Crash on exit in qt5winextras.dll Windows XP 32

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5

GUI widgets(c++) application is built with the latest Qt Creator, Qt 5.4.1 MinGW SDK(qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw491_opengl-5.4.1.exe) on Windows 8.1 x64

PRO file:

```
QT       += core gui network winextras

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Everything is by defaults, no special settings. App runs and works on Windows XP x86 SP3 but when closed it crashes giving a generic windows "Send error to Windows" dialog.

Windows Logs show that the crash occured at qt5winextras.dll version 5.4.1.0 adress 0x00008009

Doesn't crash on Windows 7 and 8.1

Can this be Qt bug? How to fix this?

**Updated**

My code was similar to musicplayer example. I've compiled the musicplayer Qt's example and it also crashes.

> Qt5.4.1\Examples\Qt-5.4\winextras\musicplayer

Also, musicplayer doesn't play music on Windows XP 32

Comment: Does crash happen on the release and debug version?

Comment: How can we check a crash without any code and any information about the program?

Comment: @szulak, Release. Jepessen, sorry. Added more details

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

I think you should exec code (which related with winexras) only if windows version greater than XP.
I did something like this:

```
if(QSysInfo::windowsVersion >= QSysInfo::WV_VISTA)
{ 
    taskbarButton = new QWinTaskbarButton(this);
    taskbarButton->setWindow(windowHandle());

    taskbarProgress = taskbarButton->progress();
    connect(positionSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), taskbarProgress, SLOT(setValue(int)));
    connect(positionSlider, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(int,int)), taskbarProgress, SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
}
```

Comment: I've removed all the code which uses winextras, it's left only in PRO file.  Still crashes.